# discord bot python auto-role(help)

Tags: discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

print(discord.__version__)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('bot is online')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Members")
   await member.add_roles(role)
   print(f"{member} was given {role}")

client.run(removed)
```

what am I doing wrong here? I am trying to make an auto-join role when somebody joins it gives him a role

Comment: What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.5 [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) were introduced which directly effect events like `on__member_join`. You would need to enable it in the Discord Developer Portal under [bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiM39.png) in your application. Once that is enabled you would want to add this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```